# Unable to resolve dependencies - webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, webdriver-io

I am trying to run my WebdriverIo Specs using (**npm run test-local**) and I am getting the following error even thou I am having all the dependencies in my package.json as mentioned below

[0-2]  Error:  Failed to create a session.
Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {}}*

****npm WARN grunt-webdriver@3.0.0 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN grunt-webdriver@3.0.0 requires a peer of webdriverio@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN wdio-chromedriver-service@6.0.4 requires a peer of chromedriver@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself**.**

```
"scripts": {
    "allure:history": "mkdir -p allure-report/history ./test/reports/allure-results/history && cp -a allure-report/history ./test/reports/allure-results/",
    "allure-report": "node_modules/.bin/allure generate --clean ./test/reports/allure-results && allure open",
    "junit-report": "node_modules/.bin/junit-viewer --results=./test/reports/junit-results --save=junit-results.html && open junit-results.html",
    "test-sauce": "wdio ./test/config/wdio.sauce.conf.js",
    "test-browserstack": "wdio ./test/config/wdio.browserstack.conf.js",
    "test-local": "npm run allure:history && wdio ./test/config/wdio.local.conf.js",
    "test-mobile": "wdio ./test/config/wdio.appium.conf.js"
  },
"dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^6.4.7",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^6.4.7",
    "@wdio/browserstack-service": "^6.4.7",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.0.5",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^6.4.7",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.0.5",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.4.7",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^6.0.4",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.1.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.0.4",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.0.1",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.1.3",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.3.2",
    "grunt-mocha": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-webdriver": "^3.0.0",
    "junit-viewer": "^4.11.1",
    "node-excel-to-json": "0.0.3",
    "selenium-standalone": "^6.20.0",
    "underscore": "^1.11.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.2",
    "wdio-json-reporter": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, it would help if you post your package.json, and the code for getting to this error

Comment: @francisduvivier and i have a conf file **wdio.local.conf** with contents as below `const { config } = require('./wdio.shared.conf')

exports.config = {
    ...config,
    ...{
      services: ['selenium-standalone'],
      capabilities: [
          {
            maxInstances: 5,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            'goog:chromeOptions': {
                //headless: true
            }
        },`

Comment: It doesn't look like webdriverio@^5.1.0 is in your package.json. You are probably not adding the dependency in the right way.

Comment: @francisduvivier even after adding those dependencies, I am getting `[0-1]  Error:  Failed to create session.
Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {}}
[0-0]  Error:  Failed to create session.`

Comment: Sorry man, this project looks really weird, I think you should try starting from scratch following the "getting started" https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted.html. If that does not work then it will be a really lot easier for people to help with it. And if it does work, then you can probably see what the difference is between your project and the simple getting started project to make it work. Good luck.

Comment: Got this working with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,maxinstance=1"`. Looks like a selenium standalone server issue. Had to run it manually and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure selenium standalone server is up and running

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,maxinstance=1`

The above command did the trick for me!